# react js oauth2 login using react and spring boot shows auth window

Tags: ajax, reactjs, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have implemented the oauth2 server using spring boot and reactjs.

Server side working ok, in first step I want to get token using username and password here is my react login or get

```
export const dologin = (username, password) => {

  let details = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    grant_type: 'password'
  };

  let formBody = [];
  for (let property in details) {
    let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }


  return fetch('/oauth/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('someclientid:dTHfdd4TRDvcsaSS'),
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    },
    body: formBody.join("&")
    }).then(res => {
      return res.json();
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

However if I send request, I get http auth window alert on the browser even I am accepting json.

```
'Accept': 'application/json',
```

Not sure why it is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The modal popup is triggered because you are configured a **basic authentication** when you send this header:

```
'Authorization': 'Basic...'
```

Try to use **Bearer** instead **Basic**

## oauth2 flow

The flow of the application will be the following:

- (1) Your users will start the web application.
- (2) As they were not signed in before, you web app will show them a login screen (a page provided by the authorization server).
- (3) After authenticating, the authorization server will provide your web app a code.
- (4) The web app will issue a request to a token endpoint to exchange this code for an access token and/or an id token.
- (5) After getting back these tokens, the web app can consume the endpoints of your private rest apis **sending** one of these **tokens** as header.
- (6) Your private rest apis must validate if token of the web app (header) is valid by sending it to one endpoint of the authorization server
- (7) If token is valid, your api rest is allowed to respond to the web client. For instance a json with information of user, perform an update of customer order details, etc

Here some oauth2 flows

[image: azure oauth2]
[image: oauth2 flow]
[image: oauth2 flow]

In order to perform the steps (2), (3) and (4) you will need clientId, clientSecret and other **sensitive values**, so I suggest you, to perform these steps in the **backend** of your **frontend**!. I know this sounds crazy but with the next example you will understand:

If you host the build of your react.js app in a simple server like apache http or nginx, **this is the backend of your frontend**

The disadvantage of these servers is that they are only used to serve the static assets not to perform complex steps.

In this case you can use

- node.js with [passport js](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-quick-introduction-to-oauth-using-passport-js-65ea5b621a) module. Also check [this](https://github.com/utec/passport-autoconfigurator)
- php, ruby, etc