# How implement a basic IAM oauth2 flow with spring security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, amazon-iam

I am currently developing using spring security oauth2.

Currently, the frontend is SPA, and it is developed as react that operates with client side redering.

My rest api has the spring security starters libraries. But I don't know how to use oauth2 flow provided by spring.

So my question is: Can I use spring security as IAM to protect my web and api?

Does spring security have the known oauth2 grants and how use them ?

- Implicit grant
- Client Credentials Grant
- Password grant

Comment: In this part **If I want to use password grant authentication, do I need to have a backend server that holds the client secret and client ID for the frontend?**, why client/secret is required in password grant authentication? Maybe you might say: **If I want to use password grant authentication, do I need to have a backend server that holds the user/password sent by the frontend?**

Comment: Does your application have a login form?

Answer (score 2):

### Don't use implicit grant

It is not recommended to use the implicit flow (and some servers prohibit this flow entirely) due to the inherent risks of returning access tokens in an HTTP redirect without any confirmation that it has been received by the client.

source: https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/

With implicit grant, access token is returned immediately without an extra authorization code exchange step. This extra step is usually performed in your backend.

### Web > token > Api

SPA frontend and its Rest Api is a very common approach, used since simple startups until big companies. The flow summarized is:

- Your users will start the web application.
- As they were not signed in before, you web app will show them a login screen (a page provided by the authorization server).
- After authenticating, a [consent form](https://www.oauth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/oauth_authorization_screen.png) is showed to the user.
- After user consent, the authorization server will send you an authorization code.
- The web app will exchange this code for a token.
- After getting back this token, the web app **store it in the client(browser)** and send it as a header when apis needs to be consumed.
- Your private rest apis must validate if token of the web app (header) is valid by sending it to one endpoint of the authorization server
- If token is valid, your api rest is allowed to respond to the web client. For instance a json with products, employes, some update of customer order details, etc

For this flow to work, you will need:

- web spa with a hint of backend. Backend is required because you cannot have a proper user session in static solutions like apache or nginx.
- authentication and authorization server: Known as identity and access management (IAM) or some third app which provide you the basic oauth2 endpoints to manage a proper security for your apps.
- your apis: foo-api , bar-api, baz-api, etc

### spring security

In the minimal scenario in which:

- you will have only **one web + one rest api**, and nothing more in the future (mobiles, iot, etc)
- you don't have an authentication/authorization server
- you have a mix of functional apis (employee, products, etc) and its security (spring-security) in just **one artifact**
- you don't need user session in your web
- you don't need a logout feature

Flow could be reduced to:

- Your users will start the web application.
- As they were not signed in before, you web app will show them a login screen (a page provided by **spring-security**).
- <s>After authenticating, a [consent form](https://www.oauth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/oauth_authorization_screen.png) is showed to the user.</s>
- <s>After user consent, the authorization server will send you an authorization code.</s>
- <s>The web app will exchange this code for a token.</s> Since your api is using Spring security, the token generation is covered.
- After getting back this token, the web app **store it in the client(browser)** and send it as a header when apis needs to be consumed.
- <s>Your private rest apis must validate if token of the web app (header) is valid by sending it to one endpoint of the authorization server</s> I think the spring security chain filters handle this.
- If token is valid, your api rest is allowed to respond to the web client. For instance a json with products, employes, some update of customer order details, etc

[image: oauth2 with spring security]

Here some samples of token generation and protected endpoints with spring security. I will try to upload a ready to use sample:

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-jwt-authorization-and-authentication-in-spring/

#### IAM

If you will have more applications and complex scenarios in the future, I advice you to choose some [open-source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049409/3957754) iam like:

- Glewlwyd,Keycloak,OAuth.io,ORY Hydra,SimpleLogin,SSQ signon,

Commercial services like:

- Auth0,Curity Identity Server,FusionAuth,Okta,Red Hat Single Sign-On,cidaas.

Or try to develop a new one using pure spring-security

### Lectures

Some recommended answers with more oauth2 details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123945/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049409/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57351168/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63093136/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621986/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211493/3957754

Comment: First, thank you for your kind answer.

I've read everything you wrote down, but there is something I don't understand well.
Is there a function to generate a token with only Spring Security without an authentication server in the scenario you told me? (Are you talking about generating the token yourself, not using the oauth library?)

*If you can do that, please refer to the link.

Comment: In addition, if authentication is performed through an external authentication server such as the Google login function, does the access token delivered to the front become Google's access token?

Or is the Google login process only authentication and the access token passed to the front is the access token of my own authentication server?


Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: #1 I added a post in which you can see how generate a token and how use it to protect your endpoints.  #2 Very nice question about google. As a summary you can re-use the access_token of google (in this case, spring security is not required) or use google as just one step extra in your security flow with spring security. #3 Try to earn more reputation to use this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228089/iam-and-oauth2-with-spring-security